# CoCreateInstance of a COM+ component fails with 0x8007007e “The specified module could not be found”

Tags: c++, windows, com+

I have a COM+ component running as an in-process server (library application) in the COM+ catalog under 64 bit Windows Server 2008 or 64 bit Windows 7. If I install a 32 bit version of the component in C:\Windows\System32 and run:

```
HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_MyClsID, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_MyInterface, reinterpret_cast<void**>(&_interfaceInstance));
```

from a 32 bit application everything works. Likewise if I install a 64 bit version of the component under C:\ and call CoCreateInstance from a 64 bit application it runs as expected. However if I install a 64 bit version of the component under C:\Windows\System32 and attempt to call CoCreateInstance from a 64 bit application the return value is 0x8007007e, meaning "The specified module could not be found". I am particularly careful about unregistering the component before moving it. I have also checked that the InProcServer keys in the registry point to the actual path to the COM+ dll. What I can't understand is why everything works except for the 64 bit install under C:\Windows\System32??? Any thoughts or ideas hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Installing your component to `C:\Windows\System32` seems like a bad idea in general: that folder is owned by the OS and isn't intended for the installation of user programs.

That said, you're probably being bitten by [file system redirection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384187.aspx): when a 32-bit program access `C:\Windows\System32`, it's actually redirected to `C:\Windows\SysWOW64`. If your installer is 32-bit, it's not actually writing your 64-bit component to the folder you expect. When your 64-bit app runs, it tries to find the component in the "real" `System32` folder and fails to find it.

I would recommend installing the two different versions of your component to `x86` and `x64` subfolders of a new folder under `%ProgramFiles%`.

Comment: There's also registry redirection which will bite you. The answer is to use a 64-bit installer if you are installing a 64-bit component.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the replies, much appreciated. We aren't using installers at all with development testing, both the component and the executable are simply copied to their respective locations. We also wrote the COM registration logic. However I suspect you are both 100% on the money when you say some sort of redirection is involved in Windows attempts to locate the component. I think we need to rethink the decision to install to System32. Big thanks once again.